# Adding a Data Field in VBA Access

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

I am trying to add a data field in my VBA access script where I take the count of how many times a number was dialed on a certain date. I have the column set up to return the Dialed Number and Days, but I am having trouble finding the correct format online for doing a .AddDataField for my other needed column. It is saying that I need an '=' sign for my .AddDataField function. What is the proper formatting?

```
Set xlPT = xlPC.CreatePivotTable(xlSheet.Range("A3"), "Aux Code Report")

With xlPT

    .AddDataField("Dialed_Mod_Num","DialedModTotal",xlCount)

    With .PivotFields("Dialed_Mod_Num")
     .Orientation = xlRowField
     .Position = 1
     .Caption = "DialedMOD_Num"
    End With

    With .PivotFields("LocalDay")
     .Orientation = xlRowField
     .Position = 2
     .Caption = "Date"
    End With

 .TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium2"
 .RowAxisLayout 1
 .InGridDropZones = True
 .DisplayErrorString = True
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.AddDataField .PivotFields("Dialed_Mod_Num"), "DialedModTotal", xlCount
```

Comment: It says 'DataTypeError Mismatch' I have it formatted from the table I am retrieving the data as in Number format, but it comes in from the SQL Server as a varchar. But when I CAST(Dialed_Num as Int) to make sure it comes into my Access table as an Int, it says the ODBC Call Failed.

Comment: I'm sorry. "Dialed_Mod_Num" should have been a reference to the Pivot Table field. I have updated my answer. If that doesn't fix it, someone else will probably have to take a stab at it.